# Using autossh to create a persistent, multiplexed ssh connection without any port forwarding?

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to use autossh to maintain an ssh session configured for multiplexing. This way I can write scripts on my localhost that take advantage of the persistent ssh connection. I'm having trouble getting ssh and autossh to behave consistently and am hoping someone can help me out.

Contents of my ~/.ssh/config file...

```
 Host cg*
    ServerAliveInterval 300
    ServerAliveCountMax 2

    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/control:%h:%p:%r
    ControlPersist yes
```

Creating the master ssh connection...

`$ ssh -fNn jehudson@cg5`

`$ ps aux | grep ssh`

`jehudson 11813  0.0  0.1   5744   628 ?        Ss   18:42   0:00 ssh -fNn cg5`

Checking to see if the connection is being multiplexed...

`$ ssh -O check cg5`:

`Master running (pid=11813)`

Opening and closing a session over the master session...

`$ ssh cg5`

`$ ...`

`$ exit`

`Shared connection to cg5 closed.`

That much appears to be working correctly. Now I want to do the same thing but using autossh.

Terminating the master connection...

`$ ssh -O exit cg5`

`Exit request sent.`

Opening the connection via autossh...

`$ autossh -M 0 -fNn jehudson@cg5`

`$ ps aux | grep autossh`

`jehudson 11826  0.0  0.1   3660   772 pts/1    S+   18:45   0:00 grep --color=auto autossh`

(!) Well that's weird... autossh doesn't seem to be starting, or if it is it is very quickly dying.


`$ ps aux | grep ssh`

`jehudson 11823  0.0  0.1   5744   916 ?        Ss   18:45   0:00 ssh: /home/jehudson/.ssh/control:cg5:22:jehudson [mux]`

(!?) It appears the tunnel was opened, but after creating it autossh didn't continue to maintain it! And why is the control file listed in the process description this time?


`$ ssh -O check cg5`

`Master running (pid=11823)`

Clearly, a multiplexed ssh session has been established, but it's not being monitored by autossh.

I've tried different combinations of the flags accepted by autossh but I can't find a way to open up a simple, multiplexed ssh connection, send it to the background, and have it monitored by autossh. Please let me know if you see something I may have missed or if you have a suggestion for me to try.

Answer (score 6):

It appears `autossh` does not play well with `ControlPersist`. If you leave `ControlPersist` enabled the connection will terminate after the persist period. So:

`autossh -f -M0 -N -oControlPersist=no $DEST`