# Automating autossh?

Tags: ssh, autossh

Adding

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%C
ControlPersist yes
```

to `~/.ssh/config` automatically creates a control connection that stays alive for a long time. This works at home where Internet is stable but not when mobile, changing IPs etc. autossh, on the other hand, restarts ssh when it goes away. An ideal combination would be

1. An ssh connection is initiated
2. If there is no control socket, it starts autossh which starts another ssh to the same host establishing the control socket.
3. It now uses as the socket as a slave.

Manually starting autossh to everywhere I might `git push` to is just not feasible.

I read [Using autossh to create a persistent, multiplexed ssh connection without any port forwarding?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198965/9452) and I understand `ControlPersist` will need to go, that's OK, the workflow above makes it absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: No, I want `git` to be faster. It's much faster over existing connections because it doesn't need to re-auth.

Comment: ??? VPN doesn't need to reauth, and it includes the capability to reconnect when connection lost, or when getting new ip (and the tcp socket also won't lost, while you lost the existing connection while reconnecting ssh). You wanna a stable vpn connection to your server, but instead of vpn you're trying some hackish solution via ssh. Try openvpn!

Comment: When you do `git push` or `git pull` over SSH it authenticates for every single one of those. That's a waste. And it's not my server, I am using about a dozen different remote repositories and that's just git, there's another dozen or more client servers. It's so much nicer over exisitng connection. Try `ControlMaster`! :P

Comment: Yes, the same what i said. Don't use ssh as a primitive vpn, just use vpn as a vpn.

Comment: This makes no sense. How would a VPN speed up git push to github, as an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80906/discussion-between-chx-and-ipor-sircer).